Are there philosophers who believe mathematical objects exist, but not forever?
I am a mathematical platonist, because I believe mathematical objects exist. Moreover, I believe they exist eternally and timelessly. However, are there philosophers who only believe the first part? That is, they believe that mathematical objects exist, but they also believe that at one time, mathematical objects will no longer exist. I would be very interested to read the writings of such philosophers, to know what arguments they have given in favor of their view.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

As Kristian Berry comments:

Some analysts say that chess is an abstract object that at least began to exist: "Other abstract objects appear to stand in a more interesting relation to spacetime. Consider the game of chess. Some philosophers will say that chess is like a mathematical object, existing nowhere and ‘no when’—either eternally or outside of time altogether. But the most natural view is that chess was invented at a certain time and place (though it may be hard to say exactly where or when); that before it was invented it did not exist at all."


Well ... the eternal question ... existence... it all boils down to the definitions. Having a need to be a little bit sarcastic (in a good way), since you beleive that mathematical objects exist,

mathematical objects: numbers, sets, functions, expressions, geometric
objects, transformations of other mathematical objects, and spaces.
Mathematical objects can be very complex; for example, theorems,
proofs, and even theories are considered as mathematical objects in
proof theory.

... it seems that chairs exist too - as transformations and re-arrangements of other existing objects (matter, geometry etc), the wheel existed too, as a geometrical object and all engineering constructs. After all, what we, do, besides rearranging materials and ideas? Has anyone ever created something that never existed in this context, that came out of nothing?
